# Error Automatización VBA excel HTML

Tags: html, vba

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto que consiste entre otras cosas el poder interactuar con una página web utilizando para ello excel y VBA para aplicaciones.

Al momento de **"setear"** checo el valor de mi variable oBrowser y arroja como valor:

> "error de automatizacion"

¿Donde puede estar el error?

Este es mi código:

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://hotmail.com"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.Ecom_User_ID.Value = "dfdf" 'Range("ReceptorNOM").Value
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

---

Adjunto imagen de las referencias que tengo activas en el proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Muchas gracias por tu atención, y si, estan activadas te envio imagen de las referencia que tengo activas en el proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿tienes activadas las referencias a Microsoft Internet Controls y a Microsoft HTML Object Library?

Comment: HTMLDoc.querySelector("input[type=submit]").click  en lugar de For Loop

Comment: Puedes probar usando un WebBrowser tambien, que cumple la funcion del internet explorer, pero en una ventana agregada al excel. Yo tenia problemas para logear en sitios con google chrome e internet explorer. te adjunto link para que veas el metodo. <a>https://blogs.itpro.es/exceleinfo/2011/06/28/uso-del-control-webbrowser-en-excel/

Answer (score 2):

Deberías tener las variables dentro del sub. Compilé tu código y funciona perfectamente, otra buena práctica es colocar antes el option explicit.

```
Sub Login_2_Website()
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://sp.booking.com"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.Ecom_User_ID.Value = "dfdf" 'Range("ReceptorNOM").Value
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
   If Err <> 0 Then
     Debug.Assert Err = 0
   Err.Clear
   Resume Next
   End If
End Sub
```

**Las referencias que tengo agregadas son:**

[image: Referencias]

Comment: Muchas gracias. También tenia el mismo problema pero me sirvió activar algunas referencias que no estaban activas.

Answer (score 0):

una formulación diferente

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Login_2_Website()
    Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer, URL As String

    URL = "https://sp.booking.com"
    Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    With oBrowser
        .Silent = True
        .timeout = 60
        .Visible = True
        .navigate2 URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .all.Ecom_User_ID.Value = "dfdf" 'Range("ReceptorNOM").Value
            .all.passwd.Value = "*****"
            .querySelector("input[type=submit]").Click '< https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Referencia:**

VBE > Microsoft Internet Controls